# How the tasks in AirFlow/DAG find the executable files, which implemented the functions that should be performed by the tasks?

Tags: java, python-3.x, docker, airflow, databricks

I would like to do some code development work by updating some algorithms in a data pipeline. The coding language is Python3 and java.

The data pipeline is based on AirFlow/DAG. There are many tasks in the workflow DAG. I need to change some algorithms in some tasks.

Currently, the DAG is located on a production system, which is a remote cluster.

I have two choices to work on the project. But, I am not sure which one is better.

**One choice**: Make a clone of the DAG on the production system and change the algorithms of the tasks that I need to update and then run the AirFlow DAG and test it on the production system.
            I have to assure that the production system is not messed up by the DAG that is still in test version.

**Another choice**:  Install docker and create containers for AirFlow. Make a clone of the DAG to my laptop. Change the algorithms of the tasks that I need to update and test the DAG on my local machine.
                But, the data that will be used to run the DAG is located in remote clusters. And, the data size is very large. I cannot download it to my local machine.
                So, in this way, there will be many data transactions between my local machine and the remote clusters, which is not efficient.

The data is located in databricks/AWS. The tasks in DAG are implemented by python3 and the tasks' functions are implemented by java.

Also, I would like to know how the tasks in a DAG find the executable files, which can perform the task's functions.

There are 80+ java files, which perform the functions of all tasks defined in the DAG.

I can check out the java files from github to my local machine. 
After changing some of the java code and pushing it to github as a new branch, how to let the tasks in the DAG know where and how to find the new updated executable files, which are generated by the new java code ? How to assure that each task finds its corresponding executable file ?

I am a little bit confused by the relationship between Docker, AirFlow, databricks, github, AWS/S3.

I think Docker provides virtualization for AirFlow, and AirFlow provides the services of managing jobs/tasks and their dependency and AWS/S3 provides data storage.

But, I am not sure that databricks provide the data access and the coding of DAGs (by python) ? But, how the executable file can be "mapped" to each task so that each task in a DAG can "call" the correct executable file ?

My question is long but I think the logic is simple.

Any advices could be appreciated.

Thanks !